# How can I put my button down left in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I tried multiple methods to put button2 to down left but I couldn't find a solution.

```py
class StartPage(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        
        ttk.Style().configure("Accent.TButton", font=("Arial", 10))
        
        # label of frame Layout 2
        label = ttk.Label(self, text ="Startpage", font = ("Arial", 16))
        
        # putting the grid in its place by using
        # grid
        label.grid(row = 0, column = 4, padx = 10, pady = 10)
        
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text ="Page 1", style='Accent.TButton',
        command = lambda : controller.show_frame(Page1))
        
        self.time_label = ttk.Label(self, font = 'calibri 30 bold', foreground = 'white')
        self.time_label.grid(column=3, row=10, sticky='nsew')
        
        # putting the button in its place by
        # using grid
        button1.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
        
        ## button to show frame 2 with text layout2
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text ="Page 2", style='Accent.TButton',
        command = lambda : controller.show_frame(Page2))
        
        # putting the button in its place by
        # using grid
        button2.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, side="left", anchor="sw")
        
        self.canvas = Canvas(
            self,
            height=200,
            width=200,
            bg="#fff"
            )
        
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(50, 20, 150, 80, outline="#fb0", fill="#fb0")
        
        self.clock()
```

Comment: Try `button2.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, x=0, rely=1, anchor="sw")`.

Comment: That just made it on the left

Comment: No it should be placed on the bottom-left corner of its parent frame.

Comment: I will add a picture of what I get

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFwnV.png

Comment: How do you put the frame, i.e. `StartPage`? [This is what I get](https://imgur.com/a/GQMYDIS).

Comment: Ok wait I will show you the code

Comment: This is the first half https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEVP0.png

Comment: This is the second half https://i.stack.imgur.com/Swkwq.png

Comment: This is the last https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcE47.png

Comment: Note that `StartPage` is created inside `root` window instead of `App` frame.  If you set the background of `StartPage` to other color, you will see that it does not occupy all the space of `root` window.  Also you should post the code (in text, not images) in the question to make it a [mre].

Comment: Yeah I tried to put it in text but couldn't so I just did pictures, ok so I should create it under app frame instead and how can I do that